# endValue as Percentage Usage

Tags: javascript, smartface.io

Can I use endValue as percentage?

```
Pages.Page1.ImageButton1.animate({
...
endValue : 30,
...
});
```

What is type of endValue? Pixel? So, How I can use as percentage? I tried %30 or 30% but didn't work.

Comment: where do you use the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it as  String:

```
Pages.Page1.ImageButton1.animate({
...
endValue : "100%",
...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Take this full code of example;

```
Pages.Page1.ImageButton1.animate({
    property : 'Y',
    endValue : '30%',
    motionEase : SMF.UI.MotionEase.plain,
    duration : 3000,
    onFinish : function () {
        //do your action after finishing the animation
    }
});
```